# Where to buy training licenses for learning ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

A client of mine wants me to do some work with C# and ArcObjects.  However, I have no real experience with C# (or much ArcObjects except with Java to be honest).  Rather than outsource the work, I thought I'd treat it as a *personal* training opportunity, which I've not done for many years; can anyone recommend a cheap resource for purchasing ArcObjects (C#), or a method of buying one solely for training purposes (clients have their own copy)?

I have chanegd this to outline I do not need, per se, training media, or details (although I am sure that will follow), but the actual software; I do nto want to shell out for commercial rates, if it is just for my own use.

Comment: I'm sorry about the automatic downvote that was added during a previous merge.  To compensate, I have added my own upvote.  (AFAIK, there's no way for mere mortals unilaterally to change someone else's vote, even when it's a system vote.  A bit of a bug in the merging process there: I'm [looking into it](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/628/glitch-in-the-merge-unmerge-process).) But please clarify what you mean by "resource" so that this question attracts appropriate answers.

Comment: So from what I understand this question is not about training but about software licensing/procurement?

Comment: @blah238 Yes, apologies for any confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have an ArcGIS Desktop license, you can develop for ArcGIS Desktop applications already using one of the ArcObjects [SDKs](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgissdks/10.0/about) (included on the ArcGIS Desktop installation media). As for an IDE, since you are interested in using C#/.NET, I'd recommend the free [Visual Studio C# Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2008-editions/express).

If you need an ArcGIS Desktop license, you can request a free 60-day ArcEditor-level trial [here](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/arcgis/eval10/evalhelp/index.cfm).

If you're a student or educator you can get a 1 year ArcInfo version (Education Edition) through your university.

If you are or become serious about development (selling software/contract development work), or need to develop for ArcGIS Engine or Server, you should invest in an [EDN subscription](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/edn/index.html) which gives you access to the full ArcGIS product stack to develop against (an ArcGIS Desktop license is an extra-cost addition).

Comment: Actually; EDN out of the box doesn't give you the desktop side, only Servers and ArcEngine; you can by addons for desktop but remember these are yearly costs; not perpetual. While ArcEngine is a good point; it differs greatly from ArcGIS Desktop development since you have to build totally from the ground up. While it was a good effort to replace MapObjects, it hasn't taken off as well because of the costs for RunTime install licenses.

Comment: You are right, I added a bit of clarification.

Comment: Wow $4000 - Might have to go and pimp myself out...

Comment: @Hairy; that is 4K each year.

Comment: @D.E.Wright I Know!!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for training/resource materials you can find just about everything you need to know at [ArcGIS Help for .NET Developers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ArcObjects_Help_for_NET_developers/0001000002zs000000/).

And if you want to quickly learn the basics of ArcObjects I'd recommend [Getting to Know ArcObjects](http://books.google.com/books/about/Getting_to_know_ArcObjects.html?id=JvWLkqnCIRcC) by Robert Burke. It's a bit out of date (uses VBA), but it's easy to follow and adapt to C# syntax.

Comment: I already have the Burke book, and it's grand thanks for mentioning it.  It looks like I am going to have to shell out for a license for arcObjects me thinks!